Please help Preacher Marcus Understand why his question was closed
A new user with strong potential to become a regular contributor had his first question closed without explanation. Also he was not properly welcomed to the group. I tend to think the question was legit but I won't argue that point. Here, I merely want to draw the moderators' attention to the issue. We want to increase participation from people like this, who clearly has a lot to offer. Sorry if this is not the place to bring this up. I don't know how to contact moderators directly.

The wording some instructions may have been tailored to the culture of that time. concerned me and I added the comment . . . The decision to close appears to be both a community decision and a Moderation decision. There is a great danger in confining the words of the apostles to the time in which they lived. The word of the Lord endureth for ever. There are many people who wish to disobey the word of God and they comfort themselves with the idea that it simply does not refer to themselves due to historical, geographical or cultural differences.. But I did not vote for closure myself.

I re-opened it after a hefty edit.
It seemed to me as a new user's question about a specific hermeneutic, namely cultural-historical context and, specifically, how to use it.
Hanging in there while being reviewed with candid feedback can be difficult. One of my first answers on this site was deleted by the moderators. Bible study is not for the faint of heart because we must be painfully honest with ourselves.
In Bible school, one of my most valued conversations was with a classmate. His father was a modern scholar who just took a teaching job at the school. That classmate went on to work as a Christian lawer downtown—and lawyers swim among the sharks. Things he told me about needing to be responsible in Bible study were the most painful words I ever received at school, but the most helpful. We need to be able to withstand that if we really want to understand the Bible.
At the same time, we need patience. It is good that you brought this to our attention. I don't think the other moderators will object to the direction it took. The question just needed to be refined, and it brings value. Some of the comments also explained the gravity of the issue. For me, that told me why it needed to be addressed.
That user would indeed have a very promising future on the site, regardless of how difficult it is to join anything new.
When applying the Bible to specific cultural situations in ancient history, then learning a timeless principle to apply today is generally the exegetical process. As long as that process applies the original intent to our modern situation accurately, it is good. But, twisting the text's meaning would be bad.
It was a good question that needed clarity so we know it is both valuable and on-topic. Now, it is.
